# PythonのClass内部から外部の変数を参照する

Tags: python

＜状況＞
Python (Cython)を使って、以下のようなコードを書いています (かなり簡略化しています)。

```
cdef class Branch:
   def __cinit__(self):
      self.param = npr.beta(1.0, gamma)

def make_branch():
   for i in range(length):
      new_branch = Branch()

def main(int length, double gamma):
   make_branch(length)
```

Cythonでの関数`main(length, gamma)`には、通常のPythonのファイルから作るべきBranchの数とそのパラメータ`gamma`を渡しており、Branchを作るたびにBeta(1.0, gamma)からparameterを作ります。

＜質問＞
Branchクラスから、直接的に`main()`にある`gamma`を参照することはできますでしょうか。以下のように、順々に`gamma`を渡していけば問題ないことはわかるのですが、実際は構造が複雑で、いちいち変数を渡して行くのが面倒なので、別の方法があればと思い質問させて頂きました。
よろしくお願い致します。

```
cdef class Branch:
   def __cinit__(self, gamma):
      self.param = npr.beta(1.0, gamma)

def make_branch():
   for i in range(length):
      new_branch = Branch(gamma)

def main(int length, double gamma):
   make_branch(length, gamma)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Branchとmainは別モジュールということでよいでしょうか。同モジュールならグローバル変数(関数のスコープ外で変数定義)すれば良いと思います。

別モジュールならば、以下のような感じでしょうか

config.py

```
gamma=0//初期値
```

main.py

```
import config    
config.gamma = gamma
```

Branch.py

```
import config
#import main 必要なら
print(config.gamma)
```

参考：
https://docs.python.org/2.7/faq/programming.html#how-do-i-share-global-variables-across-modules

Comment: ありがとうございます。例えば、`config.py`の中の`main()`という関数の中にgammaがあると`NameError`になるのですが、これはどう対処すべきでしょうか。

Comment: config.pyは参照用のグローバル変数(モジュール変数)を定義する目的のみに用意されたモジュールなので、コンストラクタ等の目的以外では特に処理は持たない想定です。ただ、スコープ内変数とグローバル変数が名前が被っても、grobal識別子をつけない限りスコープ内変数として解釈されるのでNameErrorにはならないはずですが・・・

Comment: 今、ご回答の中にある`Branch.py`に相当する箇所をCythonで書いているのですが、その点が影響しているのでしょうか...少し調べて見ます。ありがとうございました。